# DELL U2410 Monitor(Display Port) & Graphic card

Tags: hdvideo

I was looking for a 24" monitor and bought the Dell 24" inch ultra sharp monitor which has DisplayPort( new keyword for me) seems it is equivalent to HDMI.

Now I would like to enhance the display capabilities for my laptop and desktop(both have VGA output as of now). Couple of questions in mind:

1. Is there a single HD graphic card which i could use for both desktop and laptop? I understand it has to be external but if its costly then I would stick on internal graphic card for my desktop. Please recommend external if its cost effective else I would go for internal one(Budget is around $70 or Rs 4000.
2. Is there a HD card which I could use for both HD video and 5.1 channel audio output?

I generally use the computer for office work/ listening music and watching movies, not gaming.

Answer (score 0):

You are unlikely to be able to put in a 'proper' graphics card into a laptop. Most external graphics cards would need to go through USB and as such be horrible performance wise. Superuser isn't for purchase recomendations so i'm not going to recommend any cards
Now that i've totally bashed your hopes..

The good news - chances are you SHOULD be able to use your monitor at its full resolution over VGA.

AND  but even your standard discrete graphics card (or even modern integrated graphics) should be able to handle full HD - just get a decent card that supports display port within your budget. As for sound - i have no idea, unfortunately. I just use the onboard soundcard.